# Upgrading Doctrine Migrations

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am getting this warning on my codebase, here's my [composer](https://github.com/alexseif/myapp/blob/master/composer.json)

```
Package zendframework/zend-eventmanager is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-eventmanager instead.
```

So I needed to upgrade `Doctrine Migrations bundle`, but I can't seem to upgrade it, and I can't find an upgrade log. 
First I get errors about `Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration`, so I replaced them all to `Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration`. Now I'm getting

```
Compile Error: Declaration of Application\Migrations\Version20170927104049::up(Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema $schema) must be compatible with Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration::up(Doctrine\DB  
  AL\Schema\Schema $schema): void
```

I asked for a CHANGELOG https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/296

But anyhelp would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you your function is not compatible with the abstract function, did you forget to add the return type to your function?

make it:

`public function up(Schema $schema) : void
{}`

Comment: Thank you, I hope that's it

Answer (score 0):

You should start by upgrading your packages through `composer upgrade` - for example, in your `composer.lock`, you are using `ocramius/proxy-manager` in a version of that bundle that is nearly three years old, and this requires the abandoned package. The name change from `zendframework/zend-eventmanager` to `laminas/laminas-eventmanager` has happened in 2019.

A next step might be to upgrade the constraints such that you require even newer packages. For example, there are much more recent versions of `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle` or `symfony/swiftmailer-bundle`, and updating them from time to time helps to avoid problems. As the gap between the installed version and a more recent version gets larger and larger, the upgrading process gets more complex too.

On the other hand: if your code is still working properly, you can simply ignore that warning. It tells you that the given package will not receive any updates after all, but that does not mean you are in danger immediately

Comment: Yes you're right, I fail to stay up to date on my own tools. But the issue here, is that some of the upgrades do not come with a changelog so you can properly take the upgrade step.

Comment: And composer upgrade is not enough here, you would need to up the package versions in `composer.json` then perform your upgrade.

Comment: Well, if any upgrades cause further problems in your application, you would see failing test cases ;)